AttributeError: 'finance_tracker' object has no attribute 'back_button'
I have a problem when hiding buttons in the view_transaction function.
def create_widgets(self, transaction_frame):
    # Add some style
    style = ttk.Style()

    # pick a theme
    style.theme_use('clam')  # themes - defaults, alt, clam, vista

    # configure our treeview colors
    style.configure('Treeview',
                    background='Light Gray',
                    foreground='Black',
                    rowheight=30,
                    fieldbackground='Light Gray')
    # change selected color
    style.map('Treeview',
              background=[('selected', 'blue')])

    # creating tree view
    my_tree = ttk.Treeview(transaction_frame)
    my_tree['columns'] = ('type', 'category', 'amount', 'date', 'ID')  # defining columns

    # format columns
    my_tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
    my_tree.column('type', anchor='w', width=120)
    my_tree.column('category', anchor=CENTER, width=120)
    my_tree.column('amount', anchor=CENTER, width=120)
    my_tree.column('date', anchor='w', width=120)
    my_tree.column('ID', anchor='w', width=120)

    # create Headings
    my_tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor='w')
    my_tree.heading('type', text='Transaction Type', anchor='w')
    my_tree.heading('category', anchor=CENTER, text='Transaction Category')
    my_tree.heading('amount', anchor=CENTER, text='Transaction Amount')
    my_tree.heading('date', anchor='w', text='Transaction Date')
    my_tree.heading('ID', anchor='w', text='Transaction ID')

    # adding data
    count = 0
    for item in self.content.keys():
        for i in self.content.get(item):
            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='',
                           values=(i['type'], item, i['amount'], i['date'], i['id']))
            count += 1
    self.remove_all = tk.Button(transaction_frame, text='Remove All Records', relief='flat', bg='Light Blue',font=SMALL_FONT_STYLE)
    self.remove_one = tk.Button(transaction_frame, text='Remove Selected Record', relief='flat', bg='Light Blue',font=SMALL_FONT_STYLE)
    self.back_button = tk.Button(transaction_frame, text='Return to Main Menu', font=SMALL_FONT_STYLE,
                                 anchor='se',bg='Light Blue', relief='flat')
    self.back_button.pack(side='bottom', pady=5)
    self.remove_all.pack(side='bottom', pady=5)
    self.remove_one.pack(side='bottom', pady=5)
    
    my_tree.pack(fill='both', pady=10, padx=10)
    self.hide_buttons()
def hide_buttons(self):
    self.back_button.pack_forget()
    self.remove_all.pack_forget()
    self.remove_one.pack_forget()
def show_buttons(self):
    self.back_button.pack(side='bottom', pady=5)
    self.remove_all.pack(side='bottom', pady=5)
    self.remove_one.pack(side='bottom', pady=5)
def display_transactions(self):
    self.hide_buttons()
    view_transaction_frame = tk.Toplevel()
    view_transaction_frame.title('Display Transactions')
    view_transaction_frame.configure(bg="Light Gray")
    view_transaction_frame.geometry('700x400')
    view_transaction_frame.resizable(False, False)     view_transaction_frame.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\SD1_Courseworks\COURSEWORK_03\tracker_icon.ico')

    # create labels
    display_title = tk.Label(view_transaction_frame, text="The Recorded Transactions are as follows",
                             anchor="center", font=TITLE_FONT_STYLE, bg='Light Gray')
    display_title.pack(pady=20)


    self.create_widgets(view_transaction_frame)

I tried many times without hiding the buttons and creating the relevant buttons in the relevant functions. But it did not work. I even got help from ChatGPT also. But it was no use.

Move all self.remove_all, self.remove_on, and self.back_button, including all pack(), after the display_transactions() function.

Never place Tkinter widgets before function.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
